# Filter a List<Object> based on List<String> inside each Object

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a `List<Release>` and each `Release` contains `List<Attachment>`

I want to remove all the attachments from each `List<Attachment>`, except `X` and `Y` type.
I want to achieve this in Java 8.

I tried the below code. But it's not working.

```
releases = releases.stream()
                .filter(release -> release.getAttachments().stream()
                        .anyMatch(att -> AttachmentType.X_TYPE.equals(att.getAttachmentType())
                                        || AttachmentType.Y_TYPE.equals(att.getAttachmentType())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: use `removeIf` with the inverted condition.

Comment: Please be careful about `removeIf` as pointed out in the comments under @michalk's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over your release list and use `removeIf` to remove unwanted attachments :

```
Predicate<Attachment> isNotXorY = attachment -> !(AttachmentType.X_TYPE.equals(attachment.getAttachmentType()) || AttachmentType.Y_TYPE.equals(attachment.getAttachmentType()));

releases.forEach(release -> release.getAttachments().removeIf(isNotXorY));
```

As pointed out by @roookeee `removeIf` time complexity is  [image: O(n^2)]  because underneath it uses iterator and it's `remove` method.

As an alternative you could use `forEach` directly on the collection and modify every `Release` :

```
Predicate<Attachment> isXorY = attachment -> AttachmentType.X_TYPE.equals(attachment.getAttachmentType()) || AttachmentType.Y_TYPE.equals(attachment.getAttachmentType());

releases.forEach(release -> {
        List<Attachment> filteredAttachments = release.getAttachments()
                .stream()
                .filter(isXorY)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        release.setAttachments(filteredAttachments);
});
```

This nested stream could be extracted to some helper method for better readability.

Comment: since `removeIf` takes predicate, and therefore can be shortened by taking predicate outside

Comment: Please note that `removeIf` has a time complexity of `O(n^2)` (on the probably passed `ArrayList`) so a simple stream that uses `filter` to only collect the elements is preferable with it's `O(n)` characteristics

Answer (score 0):

You doesn’t need to use filer on release as you want to remove attachments not release. Use filter on attachments. Use release.stream().map     And attachments.stream().filter

Comment: I know I can do with ForEach, I was trying to avoid using forEach.Thanks @Aman

Comment: @akapti, you first have to understand every stream method. filter is used to remove or retain elements in the collection based on the condition. ‘AnyMatch’ or ‘firstMatch’ will return the first element which match the condition which is inappropriate in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I am beginner to java 8.